# How to remove the space between the underline and the placeholder text?

Tags: react-native

I want to have an underline for both iOS and Android so I'm not using the `underlineColorAndroid` prop but instead using styles.

This is the input:

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Email"></TextInput>        
</View>
```

This is the style:

```
  input: {
    height: 50,
    borderBottomColor: 'gray',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 10,          
  }
```

This is how it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWmYe.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `height: 50` from the `styles: input` or keep the space as you want.

Comment: thank you, I added the height because sometimes the placeholder is being cut in half, but I guess that's just a bug? because I just removed the height and I see the placeholder fully.

Comment: for that, you can set minHeight in styles, so it willn't cut off.